# Unable to use Unity

Tags: 10.10, unity

I use Ubuntu 10.10 and I've been shifting back and forth between the desktop and the netbook remix versions. Now I can't find the unity interface on UNR. It still shows as "installed" on the software center.
Logging back and logging in on any other mode, gives me the same interface. Any ideas?

Comment: You might have driver problems. What is the output of `glxinfo | grep direct`?(if it's more than one line use http://pastebin.ubuntu.com )

Comment: any other mode? what do you mean? when you login to anything but the netbook remix you mean?

Comment: @karthik I dont have driver problems, I've successfully loaded unity without any issues earlier.  @Roland yes. I meant UNR, UNR-2d, Ubuntu desktop, so on.

Comment: can you please run the command unity or unity --replace and post the output from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be missing the [ubuntu-netbook-default-settings](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-netbook-default-settings) package.

You can install it by

- Going to the Software Centre and searching for `ubuntu-netbook-default-settings` or
- Opening a Terminal and typing

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-netbook-default-settings
  ```

This package should also install anything else that may be missing.

If you have it installed already, you could try removing it using `sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-netbook-default-settings`, and installing it again; note though that may well change or reset some of your preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-installing unity-2d and check once? 
I had similar issues as well but re-installing it did the trick.